# This is weird. My tableviewcell won´t be selected unless i press it for 3 second

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection

I have a UITableview wich i have configured, but when i press one of the cells, it wont be selected. To select it I have to press it for about three seconds and then release it. Is there some sort of UITableview-configuration i have to do?

I have already tried setting userInteraction to enabled and allowsSelection to yes.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have any gesture recognizers in your table view?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Scott is probably correct, if you have any gesture recognizers, make sure their `cancelsTouchInView` properties are set to `false`.

Comment: It sounds like maybe your table view is a subview inside of a scroll view

Comment: okei guys, yes i had guesture recognizers and my bad...didn't think enough before asking -.- but thanks